# Is it recommended to directly edit files in the git used by gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

Is it recommended to directly edit  files in the git used by gerrit. If so how?

I have  on a gerrit server Project B which contains Git B.  Project B is a downstream clone of Project A. Project B was created using jeepyb.

I want to augment project B with extra functionality.

If this understanding is correct then i dont ever edit the git directly.

I should clone Git B, make changes, push them back to Git B as a change-set and approve the changes.

I should not make changes directly to Git B by sshing to the gerrit server and the Git B directory. This will leave me with a gerrit db out of synch and I'll need to use porcelin commands to move the git objects created from the staging area and update the  info/refs.

Comment: You think you log as `root` user into the Gerrit server and edit the bare repo on disk? Seriously, that's against the concept of any git server. It shouldn't break Gerrit completely (latest at a restart it would pick it up). If this understand is wrong, I don't get your question with all the As and Bs. What's a downstream clone? Where's project A? Please use _repository_ as the term for what you call a _Git X_.

Answer (score 0):

You interact with Gerrit in much the same way that you interact with Git...by cloning the repository locally, making commits, and pushing back to the server that you cloned from.

The Gerrit workflow is a little different than typical Git however. I recommend taking a look at the [`git-review`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/git-review) tool which makes the command-line commands a little easier to work with.